# new structure crashing in console, why?

Tags: c++, c++11

This will crash console only if I ask the user to input pizza diameter before name.

If i ask for pizza name and then ask for pizza diameter and weight it seems to work fine - this i dont get why.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct pizza_structure
{
    double diameter;
    char name[100];
    double weight;
};

int main()
{   
    pizza_structure * ps = new pizza_structure;

    cout << "Enter pizza diameter: ";
    cin >> ps->diameter;

    cout << "Enter pizza name: ";
    cin.get(ps->name, 100); 

    cout << "Enter pizza weight: ";
    cin >> ps->weight;

    cout << "Name: " << ps->name << ", diameter: " << ps->diameter << ", weight: " << ps->weight;

    delete[] ps;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add a `cin.get();` after the `ps->diameter` to account for the "enter"?

Comment: By the way delete[] matches a new[];

Comment: Thanks, worked. Had to account for the enter?

Comment: Just make a regular object instead of a pointer. `pizza_structure ps; use_ps();` and no cleanup required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing types of input between formatted using `cin >> ...` and unformatted using `cin.get(...)`

This goes "wrong" because the formatted input leaves the newline in the input buffer, which is then read as the first character for `cin.get(...)` - meaning the string is empty, and then when you read weight, it fails to read properly.

You will need to either read the extra newline with a spare `cin.get()` [and hope the user didn't add a some non-digit character to the input] or manually parse the input using `getline` and splitting the line yourself [e.g. using `stringstream` to read out the digits from the line].

Commercial grade UIs will certainly use custom read functions that are more meaningful when it comes to input errors too.

As others have said `delete []` is wrong - and in fact there is no reason to use `new` in the first place for such a small structure.

Comment: thanks, cleared this up for me.

Comment: Was a homework question. Had to use new lol...